# Cannot Find Column 2 in System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to check to see if I my DataGridCheckBoxColumn is selected or not in my three column datagrid, but when I go to check at Index 2 (3rd column),I get the error

*System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Cannot find column 2.'*

The gist of what my codes does is that I select two columns from a MYSQL statement, and then add the third column with a method

**I do not like to Databind in XAML, I prefer to do all my Itemssource stuff in WPF**

- My code is here:

On loaded I call two methods, one that reads two columns, Task and ID from a MYSQL Database and the other:

```
    private void AddCompleteCheckboxs()
    {
        DataGridCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
        checkColumn.Header = "Completed";
        checkColumn.IsReadOnly = false;
        dgTasks.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
    }
```

Adds the third column (index 2).

I have a button which calls my CompleteTasks() method, where my code fails at index of 2:

```
    private void CompleteTasks()
    {

        foreach (System.Data.DataRowView row in dgTasks.Items)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row[2])) //Fails here :(
            {
                MessageBox.Show("checked");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("unchecked");
            }
        }
    }
```

My datagrid shows all three columns but cannot for some reason find index 2, as seen here:
[image]

And here is my XAML for the Datagrid:

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgTasks" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,0" GridLinesVisibility="None" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="True" RowHeaderWidth="0">
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            </DataGrid>
```

I know you can Bind DataGridCheckBoxColumns in XAML, but for distribution reasons I only use XAML to create my screen, not bind any data, and do all my screen population in WPF.

I know this is alot of junk for such an easy task, but if anyone could help that would  be greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT** When I check row index 0 or 1 it does work, it is just index 2 that fails

Comment: Data for `row[0]` and `row[1]` are coming from your database, as you said. Where is `row[2]` data coming from? You left a lot of information out from your actual code. Please see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jstreet row[2] comes from The DataGridCheckBoxColumn as shown in my AddCompleteCheckboxs() method (from what I read online that creates a boolean field)

Comment: @jstreet the only code I did not add was my Loaded method which just does some not important stuff and my mysql statement

Comment: that's exactly my point: you created the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` using `AddCompleteCheckBox()` but you didn't add any data to it, it's empty and that's why you get an exception when you try to `Convert.ToBoolean(row[2])`. `row[2]` is empty.

Comment: @jstreet I was under the assumption it auto generated a boolean value for each cell in that column - how would i go about adding data to that column then ?

Comment: You should initialize your view model with data for that particular column. you can have initially, for instance, `row[2] = false` for all rows in your data.

Comment: @jstreet thank you very much I will take a jab at this !

Comment: @jstreet Worked like an absolute charm you are amazing sir ! :)